# Syntax Error - line 0, col 50: Error: Expected end of string, got '.'"

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

Hi I'm using symfony 4 and doctrine. This is my doctrine query.

```
public function paginationQueryByAttributes($attributes) {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("c");
        $qb->select('c');

        if (array_key_exists('model_id', $attributes)) {
            $qb->leftJoin('c.model', 'm.id');
            $qb->andWhere('m.id = ' . $attributes['model_id']);
            unset($attributes['model_id']);
        } elseif (array_key_exists('brand_id', $attributes)) {
            $qb->leftJoin('c.model', 'm');
        }
}
```

This is my car model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Model\BaseCar;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CarRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("id")
 */
class Car extends BaseCar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Model",cascade={"refresh","merge"}, inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $model;

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setModel( $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I call repository like this,

```
$attributes = $request->request->all();

        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Car::class)
                ->paginationQueryByAttributes($attributes);
```

I'm getting this error.

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 50: Error: Expected end of string, got '.'

this is the query...

```
 SELECT c 
 FROM App\Entity\Car c 
   LEFT JOIN c.model m.id 
   LEFT JOIN m.brand b 
 WHERE m.id = 2 
   AND b.id = 1 
   AND c.code like :code 
   AND c.name like :name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your join `$qb->leftJoin('c.model', 'm.id');` the part `m.id` is now your alias. Change it to `$qb->leftJoin('c.model', 'm');`